# Подсказка внутри DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

при создании новой строки я установил в ячейку подсказку с текстом с помощью XAML стиля **FallbackValue=Name**, цвет подсказки стандартный черный, возможно ли **FallbackValue** поменять цвет текста:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleTextBlock}" TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Name}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="..."/>`

Comment: Я так пробовал, но после создания новой строки, предыдущий созданный текст в ячейке становится цветом равным Foreground.

Comment: Добавьте этот сеттер в оба стиля (ElementStyle и EditingElementStyle), или в базовый StyleTextBlock

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Попробовал и в (ElementStyle и EditingElementStyle), и через базовый элемент, почти всё получилось, только когда переходишь на новую строку, то предыдущая строка с написанным всё-равно становится цветом равной Foreground.